# Remove characters between select elements

Tags: javascript

Hello this seems like a simple question but i can't figure a clean way to do this :

The aim of my developement was simply to remove some hour forms represented in a **hh:mm:ss** format.
I had to hide the selec entries for hours, minutes and seconds but i still have those 2 unhidden ugly "**:**" chracters remaining at the end of my selects and i can't figure a proper way to remove them !

Here is the HTML part generated by my JSP :

```
<span class="dateTime">
 <script type="text/javascript">.....</script>
 <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript</script>
 <select id="x">
   <option value="">Hour></option>
 </select>
 :
 <select id="x">
   <option value="">Minute></option>
 </select>
 :
 <select id="x">
   <option value="">Second></option>
 </select>
</span>
```

I can't modify this code as it generated in my jsp which is using standard classes. I would prefer to do this in javascript directly in my JSP like i did to hide the time fields.

Comment: Simply wrap `<select>..</select>:` in a div and hide this div instead. Also your markup is invalid. extra `</select>`

Comment: I edited the code thanx, as i sais this html code is generated, is there a way to do it without modifying the code above ?

Comment: Are you generating on your own or its some sort of CMS?

Comment: I'm still unable to find a workaround for this. One option is to rewrite innerHTML, but its an ugly way. I'd still recommend you to wrap it. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/jnpnu0st/). If possible find ways to get proper HTML. You have duplicate ids. wrapping script and select inside span. These are not the best practices.

Comment: Rewriting the inner Html is an ugly option in fact but even that didn't work as i have to keep compatibility with internet explorer 8+ (its working in firefox...) and IE got problems with innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```js
var dateElement = document.getElementById('dateElem');

dateElement.childNodes.forEach(function(node){
    // check if the node is a text node
    if (node.nodeType === 3)
        dateElement.removeChild(node);
})
```

I have to admit that it is not very nice but it works... :p You can be more precise on which node you delete as well ;)

PS: I assumed you can put an id on the element... if you cant, just get the element thanks to the className or try to find a way ;)